# How do I update Circuitikz (or another package) on Mac using texlive?

Tags: circuitikz, mac

Looked around the web for a few minutes, but eventually found the answer. I'm making this question here (a) to help myself find the answer a little sooner, and (b) to help others find the answer a little sooner.

Question: How to update Circuitikz (or any other package) on a Mac

Comment: Oops! I meant texlive.

Answer (score 1):

Answer: Type this in your terminal. You may need to run as an administrator

```
tlmgr update circuitikz
```

For further information, see [How do I update my TeX distribution?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55437/how-do-i-update-my-tex-distribution/55459#55459)